# Prevent installation of npm package when building next project

Tags: node.js, npm, build, next.js

I am using the google blockly package (https://www.npmjs.com/package/blockly) . When i install in and run it locally in development mode (npm run dev --> next) everything works fine. However when i try to build the project using next build, it tries to install jsdom package as well and this in turn has a dependency which is the canvas package. I dont need either of these package for my use case with blockly (since it works in development mode without having either of them installed) however i am unable to prevent the jsdom package from being installed when i build it.

How do i prevent next from building jsdom tgt with the rest of the package ? Below is the error i get when i try to build the project.

```
Module not found: Can't resolve 'canvas' in '.../node_modules/blockly/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom'
```

Here is the next.config.js file

```
const withPlugins = require('next-compose-plugins');
const css = require('@zeit/next-css');

const nextConfig = {
  target: 'serverless',
  webpack(config) {
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|eot|otf|ttf|woff|woff2|mp3)$/,
      use: {
        loader: 'url-loader',
        options: {
          limit: 8192,
          publicPath: '/_next/static/',
          outputPath: 'static/',
          name: '[name].[ext]',
        },
      },
    });
    return config;
  },
};
module.exports = withPlugins([[css]], nextConfig);
```

Any help is much appreciated.